# connect shell adb with python

Tags: python-3.x, shell, adb

I am trying to access a device from adb but it keeps loading and does not access

function:

```
def get_device():
    outuput = subprocess.Popen(["adb.exe" , "devices" , "-l" ] ,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    outuput = str(outuput.communicate()[0])
    devices = [x.split() for _ , x in enumerate(outuput.split("\\n")) if "model:" in x and not _ == 0 ]
    return devices
```

I've tried this:

```
devices = get_device()[0]
adb_ouput = check_output(["adb", "-s" , devices, "shell"] , shell=True, text=True)
print(adb_ouput)
```

I also tried:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "-s" , devices, "shell"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

but it stays loading and does not continue

Comment: There is a python library called `pyadb` (https://pypi.org/project/pyadb/) that makes interfacing with adb devices much easier. As for your question, what step does it remain loading on?

Comment: after  check_output or Popen

Comment: Works llike charm to me. Did you run adb from your OS shell with some device connected?

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries doing that as mentioned in comments. One of them is [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
print(device.shell('ls -l'))
```

Which does many other things as well which you may need after doing the simple steps you have tried.